# iTextSharp insert image PushbuttonField not working

Tags: itext

I have searched and searched and cannot find the answer to my problem.  I've tried many different approaches in my code, but I've hit a wall and I'm not sure where to go from here.  I seem to be wanting to do the same thing as these two threads:

[Trying to insert an image into a pdf‏ in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661513/trying-to-insert-an-image-into-a-pdf-in-c-sharp)

[Add image in an existing PDF with itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683667/add-image-in-an-existing-pdf-with-itextsharp)

They are very similar and the answer is the same.  However, when I use that exact code, the result is a PDF without an image.  Here is my code:

```
using (var existingFileStream = new FileStream(fileNameExisting, FileMode.Open))
  using (var newFileStream = new FileStream(fileNameNew, FileMode.Create))
   {
    var pdfReader = new PdfReader(existingFileStream);

    var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newFileStream, '\0', true);

    var form = stamper.AcroFields;
    var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;

    foreach (var field in form.Fields)
    {
       if (field.Key == "form1[0].ec_Bldg_Photo_1[0].ImageField2[0]")
       {
          PushbuttonField imageField = form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField(field.Key);
          imageField.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY;
          imageField.IconReference = null;
          imageField.ProportionalIcon = true;
          imageField.Image = Image.GetInstance(@"PATH_TO_IMAGE\front.jpg");
          form.ReplacePushbuttonField(field.Key, imageField.Field);
       }
    }
    stamper.FormFlattening = false;

    stamper.Close();
    pdfReader.Close();
}
```

I have tried to rule out all of the obvious things.  My path to the image is correct, the field is indeed a PushbuttonField when I read the existing PDF field and get the field type.  If I open the PDF in Adobe Reader and click on the placeholder for the image, it allows me to pick a file from my PC.  When I place an image in the file, save, and then read in that PDF, I can then change my code to this:

```
imageField.ProportionalIcon = false;
```

And now all of sudden the image is stretched on the saved copy.  So I see that it is changing this part but this is when I enter the image manually in Adobe Reader.  When I read in the field after I set that image in Adobe Reader and it shows correctly, I see a couple interesting things.  The field.Image property IS NULL and the field.IconReference is NOT NULL.  When I use the original code to try and insert the image, it is reversed, where Image is NOT NULL but IconReference IS NULL

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

EDIT 1: Ok so I didn't see it the first time, but I went back and checked more thoroughly and I did find that key.  Here it is:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your form is an AcroForm? Looking at the name of the field (`form1[0].ec_Bldg_Photo_1[0].ImageField2[0]`), I'd swear it's an XFA form. If it's an XFA form, you shouldn't expect AcroForm code to work. XFA has been deprecated in PDF 2.0 (that is: ISO-32000-2) because of all the people hitting the wall you've just hit. Deprecation means that it's no longer supported. You might want to get paid iText support if you still need to solve this problem. By the way, you're also using an outdated iText version for which voluntary support has been discontinued.

Comment: Wow thank you Bruno, I'm sorry for being a bit new to the PDF world of development so I'm not sure if it is XFA or not.  I have a client that sent it to me and wants me to auto fill it.  Is there an easy way to check?  If it is XFA what is the best way to obtain an AcroForm version of it?  Is it possible to use a pro version of Acrobat to convert it?  Lastly, I thought I was using the latest iText that supports iTextSharp for C#.  Maybe I misunderstood the site on that.  I'm guessing I could run into trouble if I don't update to version 7?  Thank you!

Comment: *I thought I was using the latest iText that supports iTextSharp for C#.* That's not what the official web site says: [Getting started with iText 7 .NET](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET) As for checking whether or not a file is a pure XFA file, a hybrid XFA file, or a pure AcroForm file, the best way to do this, is by looking inside the PDF with [iText RUPS](https://developers.itextpdf.com/tutorial/itext-rups-use-rups-change-your-pdf-syntax-and-dictionaries) (give us a screen shot of what's under the `/AcroForm` key).

Comment: Oh ok yes I see where I was confused.  I thought I HAD to use iTextSharp which was up to 5, but iText is the new name for it :) I had thought iText was different and was obviously confused! Ok thank you so much Bruno, I'll check out the iText RUPS page tomorrow and get you a screenshot of the /AcroForm key you mentioned.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've edited my post with the screenshot and also wanted to add that the PDF I'm working with is an official FEMA document from this page:  https://www.fema.gov/media-library/assets/documents/160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things are at play here.

**Usage Rights:**

The PDF is digitally signed with a private key owned by Adobe.

You can see this using RUPS here (in your screen shot you didn't go *deep* enough):

[image]

This has two implications:

- The signature unlocks special permissions in Adobe Reader, such as the permission to save a filled out form locally.
- Making any changes to the original PDF breaks the signature and removes the special permissions leading to an ugly error message in Adobe Reader.

This functionality is deprecated in (and even removed from) PDF 2.0. It's old technology that became obsolete with the emergence of PDF viewers other than Adobe Reader.

*My suggestion:* remove the usage rights to avoid breaking the signature. See the FAQ entry "Why do I get an error saying that "use of extended features is no longer available"?" [iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/manipulating-existing-pdfs/itext7-why-do-i-get-error-saying-use-extended-features-no-longer-available) / [iText 5](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-do-i-get-error-saying-use-extended-features-no-longer-available)

This is the iText 7 code:

```
public void removeUsageRights(PdfDocument pdfDoc) {
    PdfDictionary perms = pdfDoc.getCatalog().getPdfObject().getAsDictionary(PdfName.Perms);
    if (perms == null) {
        return;
    }
    perms.remove(new PdfName("UR"));
    perms.remove(PdfName.UR3);
    if (perms.size() == 0) {
        pdfDoc.getCatalog().remove(PdfName.Perms);
    }
}
```

This is the iText 5 code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(old_file);
if (reader.hasUsageRights()) {
    reader.removeUsageRights();
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(new_file));
    stamper.close();
}
reader.close();
```

This is the iText 5 answer.

**Hybrid Form:**

If you click on the `/AcroForm` entry, you see this:

[image]

There is a `/Fields` array with references to field dictionaries that are also widget annotations. That means that the document has an AcroForm form inside. However, there is also an `/XFA` entry with a series of XML snippets. That means that the document has an XFA form inside.

In other words: the same form description is added twice inside. You are changing a button in one form (the AcroForm part), but not in the other (the XFA form) and that leads to inconsistencies.

XFA has been deprecated in PDF 2.0 because there weren't many vendors supporting that technology. It's kind of frustrating to be confronted with forms that use deprecated technology.

*My suggestion:* I would remove the XFA part. See the FAQ entry "Is it safe to remove XFA?" [iText 5](https://developers.itextpdf.com/de/node/1909) / [iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/interactive-forms/itext7-it-safe-remove-xfa)

In iText 5, removing XFA is done like this:

```
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.removeXfa();
```

**Important:** my suggestion is to remove all the deprecated functionality from the PDF, but if the government expects that functionality to be present, then you're out of luck. In that case, you will need to use Adobe software to process the form. If that's the case, you could complain to the government that their requirements lead to a de facto vendor lock-in. By the way: iText Software is also a *vendor*. It's an open source company that offers open source software under the AGPL license. The AGPL license allows free use under certain circumstances (see [How do I make sure my software complies with AGPL: How can I use iText for free?](https://itextpdf.com/blog/how-do-i-make-sure-my-software-complies-agpl-how-can-i-use-itext-free)) If you don't meet those requirements, you will have to purchase a commercial license for your use of iText.

Comment: Bruno you are an absolute godsend!  I followed your advice and removed the Usage Rights and removed the XFA part and my exact same code I tried before now worked perfectly!!  I'm extremely happy and relieved, and I would not have found this solution if it wasn't for you.  I'd upvote for the rest of the day if I could :D  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!  Also I'll make sure my software complies with AGPL thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Always happy to help.